# iOS UIScrollView in UICollectionViewCell

Tags: ios, uiscrollview, uicollectionview, swift4, uicollectionviewcell

**Problem:**

I have a `UIViewController` which contains a `ContainerView` which further is embedded with a `UICollectionViewController`. I am trying to create a `UICollectionViewCell` that contains a `UIScrollView`. My `CollectionViewLayout` is `Flow` and `scroll direction` is `horizontal`, which when used **without** the scrollview, gives a perfect feel and doesn't roam about the area whereas when the cell has scrollview, which is supposed to scroll vertically whereas the cell is horizontally scrollable, it creates a bad user experience and i need the scrollview to just scroll vertically whereas i want the cell to scroll horizontally when required.

This is how my CollectionView is setup:

[image]

And my ScrollView:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are constraining the **view** inside the scroll view with Leading and Trailing of `20-pts` ***and*** you are constraining its width equal to the width of the scroll view:

[image]

So, if your scroll view's width ends up being `500`, it's `.contentSize` will be `500 + 20 + 20` and will scroll horizontally.

Keep your width constraint equal to the scroll view's width, but give it a `Constant` of `-40`. That will stop the horizontal scrolling.